# linkedin company logo url

Tags: java, api, linkedin-api, oauth-2.0

I am using the linkedin Oauth2 api to get the company details, but I am unable to get the company logo-url from the api. Please help me wit this.

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/7787763:(logo-url)?oauth2_access_token=ACESS_TOKEN&format=json

when I use this url I receive a empty json value

Comment: You really shouldn't share your access token publicly.

Answer (score 2):

The correct URL is:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/7787763/logo-url?oauth2_access_token=ACESS_TOKEN&format=json
```

To get a field you add /field_name after the id